# Working with truncated images with PIL

Tags: python, image, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I am trying to get the Python 2.7 PIL Library to work with JPEG images that are only available as a stream coming from a HDD image and are not complete.

I have set the option:

```
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
```

And load the stream as far as it is available (or better said: as far as I am 100% sure that this data is still a image, not some other file type). I have tested different things and as far as I can tell (for JPEGs) PIL only accepts it as a valid JPEG Image if it finds the `0xFFDA` (Start of Scan Marker). This is a short example of how I load the data:

```
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO

ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

with open("/path/to/image.raw", 'rb') as fp:
    fp.seek("""jump to position in image where JPEG starts""")
    data = fp.read("""number of bytes I know that those belong to that jpeg""")
    img = Image.open(StringIO(data)) # This would throw exception if the data does 
                                     # not contain the 0xffda marker
    pixel = img.load()               # Would throw exception if LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = false

    height,width = img.size
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            print pixel[i,j]
```

On the very last line I expected (or hoped) to see at least the read pixel data to be displayed. But for every pixel it returns `(0,0,0)`.

**The Question: Is what I am trying here not possible with PIL?**

Some weeks ago I tried the same with a image file I truncated myself, simply by cutting data from it with an editor. It worked for the pixel-data that was available. As soon as it reached a pixel that I cut off, the program threw an exception (I will try this again later today to make sure that I am not remembering wrong).

If somebody is wondering why I am doing this: I need to make sure that the image/picture inside that hdd image is in consecutive blocks/clusters and is not fragmented. To make sure of this I wanted to use pixel matching.

**EDIT:**
I have tried it again and this is what I have seen.

- I opened a truncated image in GIMP and it showed me a few pixel lines in the upper part, but PIL was not able to at least give me the RGB values of those pixels. It always returns (0,0,0).
- I made the image slightly bigger such that the lower 4/5 of the image was not visible, but that was enough for PIL to show me the RGB values that were available. Everything else was (0,0,0).

I am still not 100% sure whether PIL can show me the RGB values, even if only view pixel-data is available.

Comment: Can you provide a code that is runnable? ie ImageFile is not defined, the seek does not have a number, etc..

Comment: @HuguesFontenelle, StringIO was also used by the [PIL documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.open). I thought this would be the correct wayt to open a image data stream if no file is present. I will add an runnable code with an example picture later today.

Comment: Then it is StringIO not StreamIO :-) It didn't look like a typo at first since you do want to stream..

Comment: python 2.7 has been EOLed for > 2 years now, and is no longer supported. You seem to be working with new code - or at least with just the code you will need to retrieve the images. Just use 3.10

Comment: and second: if GIMP can read the parts of the images that are still readable, you can automate it with Python as well. (and then, yes, you will have to resort to Python 2 - GIMP development version 2.99 has Python 3 support, but it is currently in a rough state)

Answer (score 0):

I would try it with an uncompressed format like TGA. JPG being a compressed format may not make any sense to extract pixels from an incomplete image. JPEG actually stores the parameters for equations that describe the image, not pixel values. When you query a JPEG for a pixel value it evaluates the equations at that point and returns the result.

Comment: Unfortunatly I have to find a way to do this with JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with `Pillow==9.2.0`

Let's downgrade to `Pillow==8.3.2` and it works.

Answer (score -2):

I don't really know about streaming, but I think that you simply cannot access rgb value the way you do.
Try:

```
rgb_im = img.convert('RGB')
r, g, b = rgb_im.getpixel((i, j))
```